# Noughts and crosses game for 2 players

Tags: python, beginner, game, python-2.x, tic-tac-toe

This is my first program in Python that I have coded and I am relatively happy with how it turned out. I would like to know how I could make my code shorter and more efficient.

```
def one_round(player):
    #Distinguish player 1 from player 2
    if player == "p1":
       p = "Player 1"
    elif player == "p2":
         p = "Player 2"

    pin = raw_input("%s move (a/b/c for row | 1/2/3 for column):" % (p)) #receive input for player from console
    #separating row from column
    row = pin[0].lower() 
    col = int(pin[1]) - 1

    if row == "a": #changing the row letter into a digit for the index of board
       row = 0
    elif row =="b":
         row = 1
    elif row == "c":
         row = 2

    while (row > 2 or col > 2) or (board[row][col] == 'X' or board[row][col] == 'O'):
          if row > 2 or col > 2:
             print "Oops, these co-ordinates are off of the board, please try again"

          elif board[row][col] == 'X' or board[row][col] == 'O': 
               print "Oops this spot has been taken, please pick another"

          pin = raw_input("%s move (a/b/c for row | 1/2/3 for column):" % (p)) #receive input for player from console
          #separating row from column
          row = pin[0].lower() 
          col = int(pin[1]) - 1
          if row == "a": #changing the row letter into a digit for the index of board
             row = 0
          elif row =="b":
               row = 1
          elif row == "c":
               row = 2


    if player == "p1": #Determining whether to use X or O
       x = 'X'
    elif player == "p2":
         x = 'O'

    del board[row][col] #Swapping out the dashes for a symbol
    board[row].insert(col, x)

    print str(" ".join(board[0])) + '\n' + str(" ".join(board[1])) + '\n' + str(" ".join(board[2])) #Printing board


    if board[0] == [x, x, x] or board[1] == [x, x, x] or board[2] == [x, x, x] or (board[0][0] == x and board[1][0] == x and board[2][0] == x) or (board[0][1] == x and board[1][1] == x and board[2][1] == x) or (board[0][2] == x and board[1][2] == x and board[2][2] == x) or (board[0][0] == x and board[1][1] == x and board[2][2] == x) or (board[0][2] == x and board[1][1] == x and board[2][0] == x): #Checking for winner
          print '%s wins!' % (p) + '\n' + 'Game Over!' 
          return True
    elif board[0][0] != '-' and board[0][1] != '-' and board[0][2] != '-' and board[1][0] != '-' and board[1][1] != '-' and board[1][2] != '-' and board[2][0] != '-' and board[2][1] != '-' and board[2][2] != '-': #Checking for draw
          print 'Draw!' + '\n' + 'Game Over!'
          return True
    else:
          return False
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"""Tic tac toe game. (Noughts and crosses)"""
print "Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!" + "\n" + " Find a friend and start the game by typing coordinates for a 3x3 grid labelled with the letters a,b,c from top to bottom along the vertical axis and with 1,2,3 from left to right along the horizontal axis." + "\n" + "Have Fun!"
#initialising board and players
board = [["-", "-", "-"], ["-", "-", "-"], ["-", "-", "-"]]
p1 = False
p2 = False
row = 0
col = 0
while (p1 == False and p2 == False): #running game
      p1 = one_round("p1")
      if p1 == True:
         break
      p2 = one_round("p2")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Python xD!  You did a great job on it ^^

Here are my suggestions

### Don‘t code everything all in one function

there are two parts in your `one_round`

- place new piece on board
- check if there is a winner or game over

so it is better to divide to 2 functions, or more, it is best that one function just do one thing

#### Clean up lots `if else` in it

For example:

```
if row == "a": 
      row = 0
elif row =="b":
      row = 1
elif row == "c":
      row = 2
```

You can use `dictionary` instead, `board_row = {"a" : 0, "b": 1, "c": 2}` or code like `row = ord(row) - ord("a")`

```
if player == "p1":
    p = "Player 1"
elif player == "p2":
    p = "Player 2"
```

AND

```
if player == "p1":
    x = 'X'
elif player == "p2":
    x = 'O'
```

Can be replaced by

```
player_info = {"p1": ["Player 1", "X"], "p2": ["Player 2", "O"]}
...
p, x = player_info[player]
```

#### Check win

You did this in a quit straight forward code, so it is a bit long, also in python it is best to just with 79 chars in one line.

- You can list all position of lines and use a for loop to check if there is a winner(if the current player is the winner)

`positions = (((0,0),(0,1),(0,2)), ((1,0),(1,1),(1,2)), ...)`

```
for p in positions:
    if len(set([board[x][y] for x, y in p])) == 1:
        ...
        # then we have a winner, and the winner can only be the current player
```

- Or just check the lines around current piece position

`directions = (((0,1),(0,-1)), ((1,0),(-1,0)), ((1,1),(1,-1)), ((-1,1),(-1,-1)))`

```
for d in directions:
    for x, y in d:
        line = set()
        current_row, current_col = row, col
        while 0 <= current_row < 3 and 0 <= current_col < 3:
            line.add(board[current_row][current_col])
            current_row += x
            current_col += y
        if len(line) == 1:
            # Win
```

- check if it is a draw just need `if all('-' not in b for b in board)`

#### Other

```
del board[row][col] 
board[row].insert(col, x)
```

You just need do `board[row][col] = x`